# Is there a way to get the button's ID when pressed?

Tags: php, button

So basically, I'm coding a page that will have multiple divs (depending on the result of an SQL request, but that doesn't really matter) that all got the same structure (some text and two buttons), I need to pass a variable into this div to get it later.
So I had the idea of putting that variable into the IDs of both buttons (using php), which works fine.

```
 type=\"submit\" id=".$id_note." name=\"delete\" value=\"Delete\"> //id_note=my variable
```

I know that it may not sound very clear, but that's the best I can do.
 Now, my question is, how do I get this ID value, in php if possible, when the button is pressed ?

Comment: Maybe use a hidden variable rather than assigning IDs to the buttons ?

Comment: you should try <input type="hidden" name="id_note" value="<?php echo $id_note;?>" />

Answer (score 1):

Bind events to each button and then get the id attribute from the clicked button

```
$('button').click(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
});
```

If you have other buttons on your page, you should add a class to the buttons and then bind the event to that class instead.

Edit: Read too quickly.

You cannot retrieve the id of the button in your PHP when the form has been submitted.  It only processes the input elements with a name, in to an associative array you can access the value the input field had.
e.g `$_POST['form_name']`

So as in the comments, best solution would be to use a hidden field that contains the id

```
<input type="hidden" name="id_note" value="<?php echo $id_note; ?>">
```

And then when submitted

```
$_POST['id_note']; // --> id_note value
```

Comment: Thank you for the information, atleast I'm a little bit advanced, but how can I get the id_note of a specific div, because that's what I wanna do.
I made a loop that makes divs (with text and two inputs, one more for the hidden one) and at each iteration it passes a certain number into the name of the hidden input (using an array).     
But with what you told me it returns always the last number that was passed into the hidden input, I guess that's because the hidden input is always the same...

Comment: How do I do that? I cannot past in in a comment 'cause it's a bit too long and if I do "answer your question" the topic will be closed, won't it?
I did a piratepad: http://piratepad.net/helpmenow